# Enviar correo por Intranet c#

Tags: c#, outlook

Hice una apliacacion la cual el algun punto manda un correo el problema que estoy teniendo es que en la compañia que trabajo usan Intranet y me genera un error al momento de mandar el correo,usamos outlook 365, tengo que pedir algun puerto diferente o algo, este es mi codigo

```
            String userName = "email";
            String password = "pass";
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("email"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
            msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
            msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
```

Estos son las excepciones que me arroja:

Excepcion 1: WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Excepcion 2: SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.97.176.34:25

Comment: Proba con el puerto 25 envez de 587 por si esta bloqueado

Comment: Sigue dando el error

Comment: Modifica la pregunta y agrega el error que te esta dando

Comment: antes de credentials cllient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: Mira lo entiendo por tu error es que el servidor donde tienes tu aplicación no tiene acceso a internet y como estas poniendo una dirección (smtp.office365.com) requieres acceso a internet o tener registrado en tu servidor de DNS ese host si no posible tener conectar tu servidor a internet te recomiendo que le agregues un servidor de internet si unicamente tu aplicación mandara correos dentro de tu empresa pues si se requiere fuera de tu intranet es necesario el internet

Comment: desde la pc donde realizas la prueba si realizas un ping a smtp.office365.com, responde ? Ademas esta raro porque el mensaje de error menciona 40.97.176.34:25, o sea esta queriendo acceder al puerto 25, no al 587

Comment: Ya intente el ping pero no tiene respuesta y lo del error es que yo le cambie el puerto al 25